# Question for threadsafe queue from three easy pieces

Tags: c++, concurrency, locking

The following is the given code by the book to illustrate a problem:
when there is 1 producer Tp and 2 consumers Tc1,Tc2, the following code will not work.
The reason is when Tp puts data into the queue, it wakes Tc1, and before Tc1 is ran, Tc2 sneaks in and take the only element and thus emptied the queue. Then Tc1 starts to call get() which will throw since the queue is empty. And the books suggests to replace the "if(count ==0)" to "while(count == 0)", so thisi would ensure the state for Tc1 is wanted before it runs.

It only makes sense to me only if Tc2 actually has a way to sneak in before Tc1. If Tp calls notify that wakes Tc1, then Tc1 may grab the lock in which case Tc2 will not be able to sneak in and do anything. If Tc1 actually failed grabbing the lock and Tc2 actually does, then Tc1 should goes back to sleep until it is notified again. In that case, it would never goes to the line of get().

> **so my question is: Why would ever Tc2 could sneak in before Tc1 and do anything, if Tc1 grabs the lock?**

```
cond_t cond;
2 mutex_t mutex;
3
4 void *producer(void *arg) {
5     int i;
6     for (i = 0; i < loops; i++) {
7         Pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex); // p1
8         if(count == 1) // p2
9             Pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex); // p3
10        put(i); // p4
11        Pthread_cond_signal(&cond); // p5
12        Pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex); // p6
13    }
14 }
15
16 void *consumer(void *arg) {
17     int i;
18     for (i = 0; i < loops; i++) {
19         Pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex); // c1
20         if(count == 0) // c2
21             Pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex); // c3
22         int tmp = get(); // c4
23         Pthread_cond_signal(&cond); // c5
24         Pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex); // c6
25         printf("%d\n", tmp);
26     }
27 }
```

[image: graph given by the book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5ZA5.png) ![book]

Comment: `Pthread_cond_signal` wakes at least one thread so both threads might be woken up

Comment: @AlanBirtles Would it be different if I am using a condition variable from c++ lib and call notify_one? Is it guaranteed that only one is woke up?

Comment: @AlanBirtles also, even if Pthread_cond_signal wakes 2, there should only be one who succeed in locking and the other should fall into sleep?

Comment: Do not understand that if two both can grab the lock in the manner, what is the purpose of locking here?

Comment: yes only one would wake up at a time but once the first has finished executing and released the lock the second can acquire the lock and start executing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pthread_cond_wait` releases the mutex and goes to sleep in "one atomic action". However, getting woken up and re-acquiring the mutex does *not* happen atomically (how should that work in case of `pthread_cond_broadcast` where potentially multiple threads are woken up?).

`pthread_cond_wait` guarantees that upon successful return, the mutex shall have been locked and shall be owned by the calling thread. But a thread that just got woken up must not go back to sleep just because the mutex might currently be locked by some other thread. Consider again a `pthread_cond_broadcast` scenario - multiple threads are woken up and competing for the mutex, but obviously only one of them can grab it - the others would immediately go back to sleep. That would completely defeat the purpose of `pthread_cond_broadcast`.

So it can happen that Tc1 gets woken up, but *before* it can acquire the mutex Tc2 sneaks in and grabs the lock. In this scenario Tc1 has to wait for Tc2 to unlock the mutex and can then observe an empty queue.

**Update**
When a thread that is waiting on a condition variable is woken up, it tries to acquire the mutex. `pthread_cond_wait` will only return once the thread owns the mutex! So consider this scenario (the queue is initially empty):

- Tc1: tries to pop an item, but the queue is empty so it calls `pthread_cond_wait` and blocks *on the condition variable*
- Tp: pushes an item and signals the condition variable
- Tc1: wakes up, but does not yet acquire the mutex
- Tc2: sneakes in and grabs the mutex
- Tc1: now blocks again (still inside `pthread_cond_wait`), but this time _ on the mutex_

In this scenario Tc1 has to wait for Tc2 to release the mutex, but at that time Tc2 has already removed the last item, so once Tc1 returns from `pthread_cond_wait`, it will find an empty queue.

This is only one possible scenario, there are even cases where Tc1 and Tc2 don't even have to compete for the mutex:

- Tc1: tries to pop an item, but the queue is empty so it calls `pthread_cond_wait` and blocks *on the condition variable*
- Tp: pushes an item and signals the condition variable
- Tc2: sneakes in pops that item
- Tc1: only now wakes up - and finds an empty queue

But these races are not the only problem with this implemetion. `pthread_cond_wait` can have *spurious wakeups*, meaning that the thread can wake up even though the condition variable has not been signaled:

> Spurious wakeups from the `pthread_cond_timedwait()` or `pthread_cond_wait()` functions may occur. Since the return from `pthread_cond_timedwait()` or `pthread_cond_wait()` does not imply anything about the value of this predicate, the predicate should be re-evaluated upon such return.

So essentially you should *always* reevaluate the condition you are waiting on when `pthread_cond_wait` returns, and if the condition is not fulfilled, you likely want to call `pthread_cond_wait` again to go back to sleep.

Comment: As you said, Tc1 wakes up and has to wait for Tc2 if Tc2 grabs the lock. Then how could it observe the empty queue? That line of code is after wait...there should be no way that it jumps over the wait if it does not have the lock??

Comment: No, Tc1 _returns_ from wait after acquiring the lock. But since Tc2 might have sneaked in, so the queue can now be empty, causing the following call to get to fail.

Comment: that is weird? By returns, you actually are saying Tc1 proceeds without the lock, which does not make sense to me? 1st of all, why it can proceed without the lock? Second, comparing to C++ condition variable,that the wait wakes up when signaled, and only proceeds when it can grab the lock, otherwise it falls back to sleep, this wait is different? Could you be more detailed of why the wait returns without the lock?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57300380/can-multiple-threads-wait-on-the-same-condition-variable

Comment: "You also need to simply use notify_all() instead of calling notify_one() multiple times, due to various race conditions. Remember that wait() automatically unlocks the mutex and waits on the condition variable, and wait() returns only after the thread successfully relocked the mutex after being notified by the condition variable." This is what this answer says.

Comment: I have updated my answer to provide more details - I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: thanks a lot. Now this is super clear why 2 condition vars are needed when Tc1 gets blocked again.